# PHP: If $value = x I want text to = y

Tags: php, html

For example currently I have

```
if ($loggedin == 2) $color = '#008000';
if ($loggedin == 0) $color = '#FF0000';
```

But I want when `loggedin == 2` to say `Online` and `loggedin == 0` to say `Offline` instead of just 2 and 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php)

```
define('Online', 2);
define('Offline', 0);

if ($loggedin == Online) $color = '#008000';
if ($loggedin == Offline) $color = '#FF0000';
```

Comment: Should be uppercase though!

Comment: Also the variable `$loggedin` can be a string

Comment: @WayneWhitty - that's a recommendation.... OP actually had mixed case in the question

Comment: @blackbird - I missed any reference to `$loggedin` being a string in the question, where does it say that? I still don't see it anywhere, only values shown are 0 and 2, both integers

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ($loggedin == "Online") $color = '#008000'; 
 if ($loggedin == "Offline") $color = '#FF0000';
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using booleans -

```
$loggedin = true; // false; 
$color = $loggedin?'#008000':'#FF0000';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `switch` statement, this way you can accommodate for future cases

```
switch($loggedin){
    case 0:
        print 'Offline';
    break;
    case 2:
        print 'Online';
    break;
    default:
        print 'Not registered';
    break;  
}
```

Instead of print you can assign the string to a variable, and use it later.

Answer (score 0):

you can declare an array like this:

```
$arr = array(
  '2' => 'Online',
  '0' => 'Offline'
);
if(isset($arr[$loggedin]))
    echo $arr[$loggedin];
```